# Error in Salesforce SQL query activity setup

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I needed some help in writing this SQL query. I had it valid when I tried a different data extension as test. But when I tried to apply it to the needed DE. I got the below error message

> Error saving the Query field.Field 'GLOBAL_USER_ID' is a required for
> the Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your
> query text. Field 'EGUID' is a required for the Target Data Extension.
> Ensure this field is specified in your query text. Field 'UAC' is a
> required for the Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified
> in your query text.

Here is my SQL I cant figure out if it wants me to add fields or is it because of null

```
select
null as Email_address
where 0 = 1
```

Comment: Can you share more details on what you are trying to achieve? It looks like you want to clear the email_address column for all records? What about the other columns?

Comment: Hi All I want to do is clear the Data extension of all records. I was trying to create an automation that did that. I tested on a different DE and it worked fine but this particular DE gave me an error

Comment: You can do that by using a simple script activity in Automation Studio rather than trying to run this hacky sql